# Maven filtering ignoring second property on a line

Tags: java, maven

This one is driving me nuts - almost :-) I got a Java properties file, looking something like that:

```
url=${ip}:${port}
```

In my pom.xml, I enabled filtering for all property files in src/main/resources and ip and port are defined in my pom.xml.

Now, when I run maven's process resources, only the first placeholder is replaced. In the case above ip. So the resulting properties file looks something like that:

```
url=127.0.0.1:${port}
```

First, I though I might have mistyped port or forgotten to define it. So I tested what happens with:

```
test=${port}
```

Guess what, during filtering, it gets filtered correctly.

```
test=8080
```

What could that be? Why does maven (3.0.4) ignore the second property on the line? Any ideas where to look for that?

Comment: show your pom.xml. Part with "property"

Comment: Can't do anything for you without seeing your POM. Looks like you're not setting the missing property.

Comment: Is this happening from an IDE or command-line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created [an example](https://github.com/khmarbaise/resources-filtering) which also has two properties in a single line, but i don't have any problems with that. But it would be helpful to see your pom.xml.

Comment: Thank you for providing this example!!! After adding the maven-resources-plugin explicitly, it worked.